# How do I get the current month in tcl?

Tags: datetime, tcl

How do I get the current month as an integer, and as a string?

So for this month, I would want "7" and the string "July".

Is there an easy way to do this without a lot of string parsing and a lookup list for month names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is the `clock` command.

http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/clock.htm#M7

To get the textual representation of the month, use:

```
clock format [clock seconds] -format %B
```

And the numeric representation:

```
clock format [clock seconds] -format %N
```

Comment: Actually, it's %m that gives "07" and %N gives " 7" (tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/clock.htm#M52)

Answer (score 3):

My company's Tcl is at version 8.4 and the %N format does not work. I guess it is a Tcl 8.5 feature. To get around that issue:

```
set monthNumber [string trimleft [clock format [clock seconds] -format %m] 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

In tcl 8.4 you can use  %h  and it will return the abbreviated month name ( eg. Oct )